# Как реализовать такую логику?

Tags: javascript, html, css, sass, less

Имеется три блока html:

```
HTML:
    <div class="test"> 
      <div class="hide"></div>
      <div class="hide"></div>
    </div>

CSS:
.hide {
display: none;
}
```

Как сделать при дописании к классу "`text`" (родительскому блоку) класса "active" (`<div class="test active">` ) изменить селектор класса "`hide`" на `display: block;`

P.S Интересуют любые, известные вам варианты: SASS, Less, сам CSS, JS.

Answer (score 3):

```js
function addActive() {
  document.querySelector('.test').classList.add('active');
}
function removeActive() {
  document.querySelector('.test').classList.remove('active');
}
```

```css
.hide {
  display: none;
}

.test.active .hide {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="addActive()">Add active</button>
<button onclick="removeActive()">Remove active</button>

<div class="test">
  <div class="hide">AAA</div>
  <div class="hide">BBB</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

CSS:

```
.test.hide {
  display: none;
}

.test.active .hide {
  display: block;
}
```

SCSS:

```
.test{

    .hide {
       display: none;
    }

    &.active {
       .hide {
           display: block;
       }
    }
}
```